# Does $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$ have an (almost) malnormal free subgroup?

Tags: gr.group-theory

A subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is *malnormal* if $gHg^{-1}\cap H=\{e\}$ for all $g\in G$ with $g\notin H$. It is *almost malnormal* if we merely require $gHg^{-1}\cap H$ to be finite.

I am wondering whether $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$, or $\mathrm{PSL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$, for $n\geq 2$, have (almost) malnormal non-abelian free subgroups. And why or why not?

More generally, I'd be happy to know a bit more about when countably infinite groups contain malnormal non-abelian free subgroups. Thanks!

Edit: As pointed out in Moishe's answer, this really should be a question for $\mathrm{PSL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$, not $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$, to avoid the possibility of (trivially) conjugating with $-I$.

Comment: The answer is yes for n= 2 (take any maximal virtually cyclic subgroup). I suspect that the answer is no for $n>2$, the reason being that most elements in $SL(n,Z)$ will have large (rank >2) centralizers. Hence the intersection of a conjugate of a free subgroup by a centralizer of an element in it will have infinite intersection with the subgoup.

Comment: @IanAgol the question requires "non-abelian free". If one asks about free subgroups, well $\{1\}$ is malnormal, period. If one asks about non-trivial free subgroups, in a sense the infinite cyclic case is a special story. Note anyway that $\begin{pmatrix}2&1&0&0\\1&1&0&0\\0&0&0&-1\\0&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$ has a centralizer of rank 1 (although not cyclic, only virtually cyclic).

Comment: As @YCor mentioned, I am specifically looking for malnormal copies of the free group on two generators.

Comment: @IianSmythe you just said non-abelian, which in principle allows more that 2 generators, including infinitely generated. You can edit the question if you require finitely generated, or even only two generators. (It sounds more robust to require finitely many generators, since the existence of such a malnormal subgroup then passes to finite index subgroups of the ambient group.)

Comment: @YCor I'll leave it as is, either works for my purposes anyways.

Comment: @YCor In this context, any restriction on the number of generators is irrelevant: malnormality is transitive, and any non-abelian countable free group contains malnormal subgroups of arbitrary rank (including infinite).

Comment: @YCor: my mistake, but it looks like Moisha found a reference. Since $PSL_2(Z)$ is virtually free (and centerless), there are a profusion of malnormal free subgroups of rank >  2.

Comment: @IanAgol if you refer to the matrix in my previous comment: my 4-dimensional example is not great since it has a finite power (its square) with centralizer containing $\mathbf{Z}^2$. But the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}2& 1&0\\1&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$ has virtually infinite cyclic centralizer as well as all its powers (but not cyclic: there's the diagonal matrix $(-1,-1,1)$). Yet it might be that some finite index subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbf{Z})$ has a malnormal infinite cyclic subgroup.

Comment: @YCor: How do you prove that the centralizer in this example is virtually cyclic? It would disprove a theorem by Prasad and Raghunathan since your matrix is real-regular.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Let $M$ be this matrix. The centralizer preserves the kernel of $M^2-3M+1$ and $M-1$, hence the obvious $\mathbf{Z}^2\oplus\mathbf{Z}$ decomposition. So this boils down to proving that the centralizer of the upper left $[[21][11]]$ matrix in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ is virtually cyclic and this is clear (in every virtually free group, the centralizer of an infinite cyclic subgroup is virtually cyclic).

Comment: @MoisheKohan it is not hyper-regular or hyper-regular in the sense of Prasad-Raghunathan (because 1 has multiplicity 6 in the $\bigwedge^2$ of the Lie algebra, when for a matrix with 3 real eigenvalue and $\mathbf{Q}$-irreducible minimal polynomial, the multiplicity of modulus 1 eigenvalues in this $\bigwedge^2$ is 3). And the results in the paper saying that the centralizer is large are Theorem 1.14 (assuming hyperregular or R-hyperregular) and Lemma 1.5 (assuming, for a uniform lattice, hyperregular). So I see no contradiction.

Comment: The normalizer in $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbf{Z})$ of the cyclic subgroup generated by the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}9 & 7 & 0\\14 & 11 & 0\\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$, or by any of its positive powers is infinite cyclic (not just virtually cyclic). So $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbf{Z})$ has a malnormal infinite cyclic subgroup. Same for $\begin{pmatrix}5 & 4 & 0\\9 & 7 & 0\\ 0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @YCor: Oh, you are right, I was careless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you have to work with $G=PSL(2, {\mathbb Z})$ and not $SL(2, {\mathbb Z})$, for otherwise the claim is clearly false. Then $G$ is a nonelementary hyperbolic group with trivial maximal finite normal subgroup. According to Lemma 8 in

*Minasyan, Ashot; Olshanskii, Alexander Yu.; Sonkin, Dmitriy*, [**Periodic quotients of hyperbolic and large groups.**](https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.3328), Groups Geom. Dyn. 3, No. 3, 423-452 (2009). [ZBL1234.20051](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1234.20051).

the group $G$ contains a malnormal subgroup which is also free of rank 2.

As for the group $PSL(n, {\mathbb Z})$, $n\ge 3$, the situation is unclear. I do know that it is impossible to find an almost malnormal Zariski dense subgroup because such subgroups always contain real-regular elements [2] and the latter have centralizers which are not virtually cyclic [1].

The references are

[1] *Prasad, Gopal; Raghunathan, M. S.*, [**Cartan subgroups and lattices in semi-simple groups**](https://doi.org/10.2307/1970790), Ann. Math. (2) 96, 296-317 (1972). [ZBL0245.22013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0245.22013).

[2] *Prasad, Gobal*, [**$\mathbb{R}$-regular elements in Zariski-dense subgroups**](https://doi.org/10.1093/qmath/45.4.542), Q. J. Math., Oxf. II. Ser. 45, No. 180, 541-545 (1994). [ZBL0828.22010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0828.22010).

Comment: For $n\ge 4$ I'm pretty sure that each element has a power whose centralizer contains $\mathbf{Z}^2$. I'll double check.